Minimal lines' length sum that covers unit square in a way that any new line touches at least one line
Imagine unit square. You draw lines inside of it until any new line passing through this square (including any corner) would need to touch at least one of the lines. Minimize the sum of lengths of these lines.
Worst non-absurd solution is the square itself. The sum is 4 because there are 4 segments of length 1.
Another solution are the diagonals. The sum is $2\sqrt{2}$.
What's the smallest sum? With picture, please, if it's hard to imagine with text.

This is the "Opaque Square Problem." The answer is, nobody knows, but there is a conjecture no one has been able to beat. See, for example, https://kenbrakke.com/opaque/default.html – also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_set#Specific_shapes

Thank you! Tried googling the problem and asking about its name ChatGPT 4o and Claude 3.5 but was unsuccessful and lost hope.
